# Kill stsadm backup process stuck in the background

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, central-administration, backup

I used following command for taking sharepoint 2010 site backup.

```
stsadm -o backup -url http://siteurl -filename d:/filename.bak
```

While backup process running, it doesn't allow any create, update operations in the site. Therefore, to update some values on urgent basis, I wanted to stop backup process. So I closed the command prompt by mistake, instead of using `Ctrl+C` or stop `STSADM.exe` process from task manager.

From that point SharePoint is not allowing any create, update, delete operations for that site. I guess the **backup process is stuck in the background**. But, it is not displaying `STSADM.exe` process in task manager, so I could not stop it.

I tried `iisreset` cmd and restarted the SharePoint services. Also **restarted the SharePoint server**, but no use.

I also checked the content database status. It is not on read only status. I checked `Running jobs` in central admin. But there is not any running job found.

How to kill the backup process (if it is still running in background) in such case?

What else may be the issue?

Comment: Check if the backup timer job is running in Central Admin.

Comment: I already checked, but there is no any job is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [Sitelock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262811(v=office.12).aspx) might be set.

You can un-set it with the following command:

```
stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://sitecollectionurl -lock none
```